# how to plot time series data for multiple factors in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I have data of the following form:

```
Date          Factor Value
10/1/2016 4:00  107 116
10/1/2016 4:00  109 69
10/1/2016 4:00  127 85
10/1/2016 4:00  129 94
10/1/2016 4:00  131 85
10/1/2016 12:00 107 116
10/1/2016 12:00 109 97
10/1/2016 12:00 127 89
10/1/2016 12:00 129 107
10/1/2016 12:00 131 89
10/1/2016 20:00 107 96
10/1/2016 20:00 109 85
10/1/2016 20:00 127 110
10/1/2016 20:00 129 103
10/1/2016 20:00 131 100
10/2/2016 4:00  107 105
10/2/2016 4:00  109 71
10/2/2016 4:00  127 110
10/2/2016 4:00  129 69
10/2/2016 4:00  131 55
10/2/2016 12:00 107 69
10/2/2016 12:00 109 108
```

There are a total of 32 factors. For each date and time, there can be multiple factors and associated values.
I wish to compare the time series of the values for each of the factors. what is the best way to do so?

I have used the following two methods, but they don't yield satisfactory results:

### method 1:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.POSIXct(df$Date), y = df$Value)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~df$Factor)
```

plot:[image: facet_wrap figure]

### method 2:

```
      plot(as.POSIXct(df$Date), df$Value, col='red', pch=12)
```

Plot: [image: separate plots for factors]

all factors do not have data at all time points. I want a common time axis, and multiple figures showing the data for the different figures along Y (similar to 2nd figure, but better presentation). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try the directlabels package using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

```
library(directlabels)
library(ggplot2)

DF$Date <- as.POSIXct(DF$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

ggplot(DF, aes(Date, Value, group = Factor)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_dl(aes(label = Factor), 
    method = list(dl.combine("first.points", "last.points"), cex = 0.7))
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- '
"","Date","Factor","Value"
"1","10/1/2016 4:00",107,116
"2","10/1/2016 4:00",109,69
"3","10/1/2016 4:00",127,85
"4","10/1/2016 4:00",129,94
"5","10/1/2016 4:00",131,85
"6","10/1/2016 12:00",107,116
"7","10/1/2016 12:00",109,97
"8","10/1/2016 12:00",127,89
"9","10/1/2016 12:00",129,107
"10","10/1/2016 12:00",131,89
"11","10/1/2016 20:00",107,96
"12","10/1/2016 20:00",109,85
"13","10/1/2016 20:00",127,110
"14","10/1/2016 20:00",129,103
"15","10/1/2016 20:00",131,100
"16","10/2/2016 4:00",107,105
"17","10/2/2016 4:00",109,71
"18","10/2/2016 4:00",127,110
"19","10/2/2016 4:00",129,69
"20","10/2/2016 4:00",131,55
"21","10/2/2016 12:00",107,69
"22","10/2/2016 12:00",109,108'
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines)
```